# Linker error in Eclipse for a C++ project with source files in different subfolders

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, linker, g++

I have created a c++ project in Eclipse with the .c , .cpp source files in different sub-folders.
Using the Linux GCC toolchain I successfully compiled all the source files but when i reach the Building Target stage, GCC C++ Linker gets invoked and it says there is no such .o files for the corresponding source files .
But when i looked the Debug folder all the .o files are created in the corresponding sub-folders .

Please help me how to overcome those errors...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Comment: Check the linker paths in your `Project settings` so they match those in the compile step.

Comment: There is a library search path in GCC C++ Linker tab, even if i add the paths of .o files there , i get the same error